# Principal minors

Tags: matrices

How to find how many zero principal minors does a matrix have? Is there any easy way to compute principal minors?

Comment: Please read http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask. MathOverflow is for questions about research-level mathematics. Perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com would be a better venue for this question.

Answer (score 2):

For the incidence matrix $\partial(G)$ of a graph $G$ the answer is easy, as this amounts to knowing how many spanning trees $G$ possess. One can use the matrix-tree theorem to compute the answer by evaluating the determinant of the (reduced) Laplacian matrix $(\partial(G)\partial(G)^T)^{vv}$ of $G$.

For a full rank unimodular matrix $M$ (i.e., all maximal minors are $\pm 1$ or zero) with rational entries there is a related "matrix-tree" type theorem: The number of maximal non-zero minors of $M$ is $\det(M M^T)$. This is probably most useful when the matrix handed to you is *a priori* unimodular, as above.

For a matrix $M$ which fails to be unimodular the number $\det(MM^T)$ gives an upper bound.

Comment: Nice answer, but you might want to define "unimodular"...

